# What salt should I use in a bread machine recipe?

Tags: bread, salt

I've got a big book of bread machine recipes that does a really good job breaking down what ingredients perform what actions in the whole baking process and how modifying the recipe will change the final product.

One thing that the book doesn't really cover is salt. All the recipes call for salt, but they simply say "salt" which leaves me wondering if there is a specific salt I should use in my recipes.

I've been using Kosher salt because that's what I use for everything in the kitchen. I wonder if I should use table salt, instead though, because it would probably dissolve better due to the smaller granules. I also know that 1/2 tsp of Kosher salt is a different amount of salt by weight than 1/2 tsp of table salt is. I also read in another question that iodized (table) salt can possibly affect the color of the finished bread.

**Should I use Kosher salt, table salt, or some other type of salt in my bread machine recipes, and why?**

Comment: Not all table salt is iodized.  If you're concerned about any effect that iodized salt may have on the final product, then use untreated table salt.  At least at my local supermarkets, they're side by side: there's an extra yellow ribbon graphic that reads "iodized" on the iodized salt.  The untreated stuff is even 2 cents cheaper. :)

Comment: You should weigh ingredients used in baking ;)

Comment: @NickT I don't think I've ever seen a recipe in the US that lists salt by weight.... heck, most of them don't even list flour or sugar by weight unless they're from someone who actually knows what they're doing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**In general**, unless the book or recipe specifically states something different, "salt" is assumed to mean "table salt".

If a recipe were to call for kosher salt or pretzel salt (like as a topping for the loaves) it would specifically call that out especially.

Comment: I'm not going to down vote this but in just about every professional culinary setting I've ever been in generic "salt" means kosher crystal salt. Table salt should only be found in one place - the table.

Comment: Professional culinary setting does not equal "home kitchen". Cookbooks and web recipes are written for home cooks, not for chefs.

Comment: Well I mean you can follow the recipe or you can make it good. I'm not here to tell you how to live your life. XD But it's definitely one of those small things that can make a big difference. I don't even think I _have_ table salt in my kitchen.

Comment: If the OP followed the measurements from the recipes with kosher salt, the bread would come out under-salted. You're more than welcome to write your own answer that explains the benefits of kosher over table and how to appropriately substitute one for the other. That's not the direction I've opted to go with as I don't personally like using kosher salt in baking because of the grain size.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Not in a position to know, but do many chefs in professional culinary settings use bread machines?  Are there commercial versions available?  All the ones I've seen are the counter-top versions that mix/knead/bake all in the same machine.

Comment: @JS. Not really. The industrial versions of things like mixers/ovens tend to be a lot more sophisticated than what you have at home, so they're going to be better suited anyway. Some places have proofing ovens specifically for baking (I think they have them at Panera - if you've ever seen a rack of bread hanging from the ceiling and rotating, that's a proofing over)

Comment: To expand on @catija 's comment, [here's a reference](http://dadcooksdinner.com/2012/02/salt-by-weight.html/) that can be used to determine how much of one type of salt should be substituted for others.

Comment: Would a professional culinary setting even use volumetric measures for ingredients in recipes? *Especially* for kosher salt that probably doesn't stack predictably for small volumes?

Comment: @millimoose nope. Measure by mass all the way every day.

Comment: a professional baker would also dissolve the salt in a bit of liquid, negating any difference due to crystal size